Node2D position marker not updating in editor?
I have a simple script which updates the position of the child node in tool mode
@tool
extends Node2D

@export var btn := false : set=set_btn

func set_btn(new_val):
    if !new_val:
        return
    
    $ChildNode.global_position=Vector2(-100, -100)

when the function executes the position of the child node changes as evident by the Icon (green) changing it's position:

but as you see the gizmo (red) of the node still remains at the previous position and doesn't update until the scene is saved
Is there anyway to fix this? I even tried calling queue_redraw() but it doesn't work
Edit:
In this gif you can see that when I press the button the node moves however the gizmo (red circle in image) does not update until I drag the mouse into the viewport or if I save the scene
using Godot v4.2.2.stable.official [15073afe3]
Edit 2
This does seem to work sometimes:
@tool
extends Node2D

@export var btn := false : set=set_btn

var _editor_plugin := EditorPlugin.new()

func set_btn(new_val):
    if !new_val:
        return

    $ChildNode.global_position=Vector2(-100, -100)
    _editor_plugin.update_overlays()

However when all children position/transform are recursively set then the only thing that updates the markers is saving (Ctrl + S)

What version of Godot are you using? I copied your script and scene layout and the issue doesn't seem to occur for me on Godot 4.2.2.

@MeSteve95 I've updated the question and added godot version and a gif to better explain, please take a look

That gif helps a lot, thanks for providing that! Are there any functional issues that are being caused by the gizmo not updating, or is it simply a visual artifact that you dislike? It seems like that is likely an optimization by the Godot engine to reduce the number of times that the scene is re-rendered when it is out of focus. If it is affecting your tool in some way, some further explanation of how it is causing issues would be helpful to try to find a solution/workaround!

@MeSteve95 well I'm moving these position markers customly via code in tool mode, but since the markers don't instantly update it causes confusion while animating, prototyping, etc,  so I guess it does become a functional issue

@MeSteve95 I'd also be open to hiding these markers or creating custom ones which still interact in the same way but with the desired effect

Yeah I can totally see how that would make the tool feel a lot less helpful. I believe that the root of the problem is that when you press the button in the inspector, the viewport is no longer focused, and because of this, it skips doing certain rendering steps to improve performance. This is usally nice, but in your case, it is causing the problem we're discussing. I searched as hard as I could to see if there was a way to set the focus of the editor back to the viewport after pressing the button in the inspector, but couldn't seem to find anything promising.

I found a hacky way that may solve this problem, but it certainly isn't ideal. You could add logic after pressing the button in the inspector that moves the mouse's position to within the 2D viewport, which causes for it to focus the viewport and update like we're hoping for. I found a way to do this, it's super ugly but it works: EditorInterface.get_base_control().warp_mouse(EditorInterface.get_editor_viewport_2d().get_screen_transform().origin - EditorInterface.get_editor_viewport_2d().get_final_transform().origin + Vector2(15, 15)).

@MeSteve95 that doesn't work in some cases, sometimes only saving the node updates it's position marker

Yeah it definitely feels like the wrong approach, but it was the only thing I could get to somewhat work. I'm confident that there should be a way to set the focus of the editor to the 2D viewport, which is essentially what the hack I suggested above accomplishes, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation or other forum posts as to how. This seems like something you could post on the Godot GitHub as a feature request, as at the very least the documentation should have this information somewhere. Wish I could be more help, happy to discuss further if you have any ideas!

@MeSteve95 I did try EditorPlugin.update_overlays() and it did seem to work for the "mouse position in 2D viewport" workaround, however if I recursively set some children's position or transform then the only thing that updates the marker is saving (Ctrl + s) and as you mentioned I've already have opened a github issue
